# How to reform or iterate my sql result set to build map

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select

I an trying to build the following cache -

```
ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<TeamType, Team>>
```

I have 4 Database table;

> Users, FootbalTeam, CricketTeam, RugbyTeam

each is foreign keyed to a user id in users (so each team table having its own userid field ).

I am trying to iterate the following sql to build the relevant map - bearing in mind some users might only have a cricket team, some might only have a rugby team and some might have all teams

The sql i have created (is probably wrong and horribly inefficient but i am stuck!). It looks as follows;

```
SELECT * FROM RugbyTeam r, FootballTeam f, CricketTeam c WHERE r.userid OR f.userid OR c.userid IN (SELECT userid FROM Users)
```

This brings me back the correct entries - however when the results come back I have repeat rows so its very hard to iterate the result set and build the relevant pojo classes.

I am looking for something like `SELECT Distinct rows where` and the condition remains as before but i don't think this is allowed?

Please could someone suggest some ways on fixing my approach?

Thanks

Comment: what is the duplicates that you are getting? you can specify DISTINCT in your query... your query is really inefficient doing the cartesian product of the tables filtered in the where by an IN... you should just join the tables by user. and then GROUP BY user

Comment: I think you should query them separately by team type, which would give you simpler query and it is more logical since I guess that your tables don't have same columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, assuming you have a field called `team_name` in each Team table:

```
select u.userid as User, 'Rugby' as TeamType, t.team_name as Team
from Users u
inner join RugbyTeam t on u.userid = t.userid

union all

select u.userid as User, 'Football' as TeamType, t.team_name as Team
from Users u
inner join FootballTeam t on u.userid = t.userid

union all

select u.userid as User, 'Rugby' as TeamType, t.team_name as Team
from Users u
inner join CricketTeam t on u.userid = t.userid

order by User;
```